# How to check if files protected by FileProtection Complete Until First Authentication are accessible?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

How to check if files protected by `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` are accessible?

or in other words how do I know if user has authenticated at least once?

As per documentation `UIApplication`'s `protectedDataAvailable`:

> when the value of this property is false, files that were assigned the
>   NSFileProtectionComplete or NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen
>   protection key cannot be read or written by your app. The user must
>   unlock the device before your app can access them.

1. So I can not rely on protectedDataAvailable since it can still be false when user has unlocked iPhone once.
2. Can not rely on existence of SQLite file, since it may not have been created(first time app launch) or is inaccessible due to user not unlocking for first time.